# CMD only read first line of command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a dumb question, my have a cmd file includes multiple line of mqsi commands. for example:

```
mqsideleteexecutiongroup broker1 -e name1
mqsideleteexecutiongroup broker2 -e name2
```

i then run it and output to a txt file but ut only execute the first line and finish. any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
start /b /wait mqsideleteexecutiongroup broker1 -e name1
start /b /wait mqsideleteexecutiongroup broker2 -e name2
```

i dont have access to the commands, but this should work.

Comment: yeah nephil, mqsi command is actually a bat file with end at the last line, so it will end the cmd. I put call in the front as works fine. Thanks for your help :)